# How to get cordinates of selected numbers which are from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

You are given to paint a floor area of size A. There will be 12 paint buckets from 4 primary
colors with each having 3 shades (i.e. total 12 buckets). The bucket size, or more specifically,
the amount of area you can paint from each shade is given in the following arrays.
The different shades of the same primary color are shown in the same row.

- [12, 23, 14]
- [10, 30, 15]
- [16, 22, 35]
- [14, 24, 20]

**Problem & Constraints**

You need to select 4 shades to paint the floor area such that;

1. Entire floor area should be painted; also no overlaps of shades are allowed
2. "One and only one" shade from each primary color has been selected for the final painting
3. Amount of wastage is minimized (i.e. assume once we open and use a bucket, any
   remainings will be discarded)

Implement a python program to answer the following problems;

Q1. The color shades (or buckets) satisfying the above constraints (if A = 100)
Q2. The amount of wastage in the above scenario
Q3. What will be the solution for Q1 and Q2 if A = 90?

**Note:** You may use the below notation to reference each shade in the above map.

R - row index
C - column index
(r,c) - shade in (r+1)th row and (c+1)th column
e.g. (0,0) -> 12, (0,1) -> 23, (1,2) -> 15, etc.

With this, the answer for Q1 can be given in the format [(0,1), (1,2), (2,0), (3,2)]

---

**If user enter 100 system should display color code areas with their coordinates which sum are most close to 100**

**Example**

```
Enter your Area = 100
100 ~ 101(sum of areas 12+30+35+24, There for 101 is the closet number to 100)

Shades          = [12 30 35 24]
Cordinates of shades = (0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,1)
```

---

**This is my answering code**

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

colors = np.array([[12, 23, 14], [10, 30, 15], [16, 22, 35], [14, 24, 20]])

max_tot = 0

#get total of all integers which are in array
for i in range(len(colors)):
    max_tot = max_tot + max(colors[i])

#Enter Area
area = int(input("Enter your Area = "))

if(area > max_tot):
    print("Area is too long. Don't have enough paints for painting")
elif(area <= 0):
    print("Wrong area")
else:
    #get shades which are given lowest minimum wastage
    for element in itertools.product(*colors):
        if(sum(element) >= area):
            x = sum(element)
            if(x <= max_tot):
                max_tot = x
                el = np.array(element)

    print()
    print("sum of shades   =", max_tot)
    print("minimum wastage =" , max_tot - area)
    print("Shades          =", el)
    print("Cordinates of shades = " ,end ='')

    #get coordinates using manual method
    for i in range(4):
        g,h = np.where(colors == el[i])
        print("(" ,g[0],",", h[0], ")", sep=' ', end='', flush=True)
```

**Output -:**

```
Enter your Area = 100

sum of shades   = 101
minimum wastage = 1
Shades          = [12 30 35 24]
Cordinates of shades = ( 0 , 0 )( 1 , 1 )( 2 , 2 )( 3 , 1 )
```

---

You can see I have got coordinates of `12 30 35 24` is manual type. That is not a good programming method.

How can I get that coordinates directly(using better way)?

**Note that I have done all question. I want a better answer for Q3**

Comment: I think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better place for this type of question

Comment: I have already done that question. Problem is I got coordinates of numbers in tricky way which is not good method. I want answers for only Q3

Comment: Still. You want comments on implementation which means that this is rather code review

Comment: I have done Q3 but it is wrong. I show my code because I have to show community what I have tried so far. I am expecting right answer for Q3.

Comment: I'm going to give detailed answer about the maximum possible optimisation of your algorithm quite soon. Meanwhile I advise you to refuse iteration used in order to find a value of `max_tot`. `Numpy` arrays are designed for vectorised actions, it means they use 'C level' for loops which are much more faster than Python ones. You might like to use `max_tot = np.max(colors)` assignment instead.

Comment: Sorry, I've just rechecked what you've done and noticed that you calculate `max_tot` in a different way. In this case you might like to assign `np.sum(np.max(colors, axis=1))` for `max_tot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way to optimize your search is removing duplicated sum values after each selection. It's quite easy to check that there exists 45 distinct values of wastage out of 81 possible ones:

```
len(set(sum(el) for el in product(*colors)))
Out[99]: 45
len(list(sum(el) for el in product(*colors)))
Out[100]: 81
```

Almost half of them duplicates in terms of `sum` and this is unnecessary weight for your calculations. But that's not quite a big speed up. It depends a lot on a qualities of data you run your code on, mainly how wide values of each list are and the amount of lists.

I have tidied up your code to make it more efficient and readable:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def get_area(max_tot):
    # Asks to enter area and returns it or raises exception if it's wrong
    # max_tot is maximum possible area
    try: 
        area = int(input("Enter your Area = "))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Area is not a number')
    if area > max_tot:
        raise ValueError("Area is too long. Don't have enough paints for painting")
    elif area <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Wrong area")
    else:
        return area

def get_shades(colors, area, max_tot):
    #get shades which are given lowest minimum wastage
    for element in product(*colors):
        sum_of_element = sum(element) # assigning it there to avoid double calculation
        if area <= sum_of_element <= max_tot: # double comparison is possible in Python 
            max_tot = sum_of_element
            el = np.array(element)
    return el

colors = np.array([[12, 23, 14], [10, 30, 15], [16, 22, 35], [14, 24, 20]])
max_tot = np.sum(np.max(colors, axis=1))
area = get_area(max_tot)  
el = get_shades(colors, area, max_tot)

print()
print("sum of shades   =", max_tot)
print("minimum wastage =" , max_tot - area)
print("Shades          =", el)
print("Cordinates of shades = " ,end ='')

#get coordinates using manual method
for i in range(4):
    g,h = np.where(colors == el[i])
    print("({}, {})".format(g[0], h[0]), sep=' ', end=' ', flush=True)
```

The "core" of your code is in `get_shades` function. I have removed double calculation of `sum(element)` and I also put a double comparison in one row to make it more readable. By the way, it's possible to rewrite `get_shades` function in 100% functional style as follows:

```
def get_shades(colors, area, max_tot):
    # functional version of get_shades
    def cmp(x):
        # compares items based on their sum; bad items are largest by default
        s = sum(x)
        if s >= area: return s
        else: return max_tot + 1
    return min(product(*colors), key = cmp)
```

But, as you mentioned, that's not enough. You might like to reduce it by removing duplicated sums after each selection:

```
[[12, 23, 14], [10, 30, 15]] -> [22, 24, 27, 29, 33, 38, 42, 44, 53] # 9 distinct sum values
[[22, 24, 27, 29, 33, 38, 42, 44, 53], [16, 22, 35]] -> # 24 distinct sum values
[[...], [14, 24, 20]] -> 45 distinct sum values
```

This was a brilliant example of what `reduce` method was designed for. After each iteration, it takes last result, performs a calculation over next item and replaces it with a new result. It's possible to capture all the possible 45 values of sums by using:

```
wastages = reduce(lambda x,y: set(sum(n) for n in product(x, y)), colors)
```

and find a minimum required sum by:

```
min(wastages, key = cmp)
```

where `cmp` is defined in this way:

```
def cmp(x):
    if x >= area: return x
    else: return max_tot + 1
```

But there comes **another big issue**: shadings, unlike their sums, are not kept in memory. Extra function is required in order to preserve mappings between shadings and sums. This requires advanced ways of manipulating lists which seems to be rather slow down than speed up. I leave them out of scope since a lot more difficult algorithms are needed for mappings and they are helpful only if your data is bigger than the one you posted.